# Rails Audited ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: CONSTRAINT `audits.audited_changes` failed for audits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I cant make any changes on models using the audited gem because it triggers the following error message.
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: CONSTRAINT `audits.audited_changes` failed for `DBNAME`.`audits`

The whole code is functional since I can use it without any trouble on Windows 10 but when trying it on Arch Linux fails. Also it is functional on AWS Linux without trouble.

Caused by Mysql2::Error: CONSTRAINT `audits.audited_changes` failed for `DBNAME`.`audits`

The constraint is giving errors with column audited_changes JSON.

I'm using audited gem v 4.10.0, rails 6.0.3.3, ruby 2.5.8, mariadb 10.5.9

Comment: is `audits` table is exists in database?

Comment: yes, the problem seems to be some kind of wrong encoding being made by the OS (probably) since the JSON is invalid. But in Windows 10 and AWS Linux the exact same code works like a charm